# Java JSF PrimeFaces LineChart Labels

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, web, linechart

I have a problem with the PrimeFaces (3M3/3M4) library.
I need a custom axis label (it does the default scale from 0 to 5 upwards), and I need it to be from 6 at the origin up to 0.
The values are guranteed in that range (0 - 6).

As fas as I can see, the PrimeFaces tag does not take any customizing options satisfying these needs. (minY and maxY are not the right options, since minY < maxY)

EDIT: A little clarification:
Instead of the default labeling on the y axis (values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
I want to label it in reverse order, but the cartesian model does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `from 6 up to 0`? Please be more specific(with example).

Though I'm very surprised because the component `lineChart` is very customizable; it has various attributes: `minX,minY,maxX,maxY, xaxisAngle,yaxisAngle` (and many more).